# Why do I have a mysterious shadow (edges) around my container in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I checked to ensure that the following settings are off:

- Shadow
- Reflection
- Glow
- Soft Edges
- 3-D Format
- 3-D Rotation

Still, my Containers have these unusual shadows or are somehow beveled. How can I disable this or remove this, see example.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Open New Document
2. Add two shapes
3. Select shapes and Add to New Container
4. Set Container format/style to "Translucent"
5. Change fill color.

## Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I was trying to add a fill color to the container style with a grey background (the last one in the list). I was able to add a color without that shadow by picking the very first container style (the one that looks like a white box).